# Zen temples in Uji Kyoto Japan

Tags: japan, temples

I am traveling to Uji Kyoto Japan and I’m very interested in having a retreat involving Buddhism and teas, especially Matcha Green Tea. I want to get away maybe in a Temple and get the whole Zen experience.

Comment: That question is about monthlong stays in all of Japan. Uji is a small town in Kyoto prefecture (not the city) famous as the home of the best, or at least most expensive, teas in Japan.

Comment: @jpatokal OK, but there's no actual question in this post and the implicit question is an off-topic we-are-not-a-travel-agent. Is there much point reopening it just to close it for the correct reason?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Travel.SE has a long tradition of "Can I do X in Y?" questions, which are not the same as shopping questions ("What's the best/cheapest X in Y"?).  And the OP's question is pretty obvious, even though it's not grammatically phrased as one.  Don't bite the newbies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find any Zen temples in Uji that run any regular events, but apparently there is a Kyoto-based yoga instructor called [Azusa Morishima](https://www.facebook.com/azusamorishima.chakrawork/) who organizes occasional retreats at a "secret temple" there.  Here's a [Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/events/303843956887421/) about a previous event, which sounds exactly like what you're looking for (experiencing a monk's life, tea sampling, overnight stay), and per [this Instagram post](https://www.instagram.com/p/BoiUv9qlOae/), her next session will be on April 14, 2019.